# Jquery XML parsing - Get attr not working

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I'm trying to get the 'subscriberCount' from the xml data. 
My code doesn't work but i don't know how to get it working ...

Code:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Tweegamerz?v=2.1&prettyprint=true",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {
    var xmldata = $(xml).find('entry');
    var xml_summary = $(xmldata).find('summary').html();
    var xml_statics_subscriberCount = $(xmldata).find('yt\\:statistics').attr('subscriberCount').text();
    alert(xml_statics_subscriberCount);

}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! you need a double element declaration for Google Chrome

http://jamesmcdonald.id.au/it-tips/google-chrome-xml-namespaces

```
var xml_statics_subscriberCount = $(xmldata).find('yt\\:statistics, statistics');
```